# Journalism style with too many personal anecdotes and too much subjectiveness

Tags: vocabulary

Is there a specific term in English for the journalism trend of attempting to create an intimate, relatable "personal experience" while telling all kinds of stories instead of just reporting the relevant facts in an impersonal fashion?

I'm talking about written pieces and TV reports that go in circles with personal anecdotes, interviews with non-experts, and so on.

For example, I recently saw on TV a report on utility bills that started with a reporter sitting at somebody's kitchen table, with all their bills scattered over the table, and he proceeded to talk about this person's struggles to pay them. I'm contrasting this to a general plain report on utility bill figures and stats without relying on emotion.

Comment: On the lighter side, isn't the word "melodrama" fit for the context. Definition of melodrama (Merriam)

    1
    a :  a work (as a movie or play) characterized by extravagant theatricality and by the predominance of plot and physical action over characterization b :  the genre of dramatic literature constituted by such works

    2
    :  something resembling a melodrama especially in having a sensational or theatrical quality

Comment: I think you're looking for  different sub-genres of journalism, one is the New Journalism as illustrated by its most famous author: Truman Capote, anoother is Gonzo journalism and also Immersion journalism (with its sub Embedded journalism). Look up these words fro a start.

Comment: I would say that the report has been [*editorialized*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/editorialize), but a corresponding noun form of *editorialism* doesn't seem to be a recognized word.

Comment: The usual term is [*human-interest story*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/human-interest-story).

Comment: Isn't "too many personal anecdotes and too much subjectiveness" kinda...subjective?  :-p

Comment: @KristinaLopez I added "too many..." because people could argue that basically all reports today do some of that, but I was interested in the ones that are centered on it.

Comment: Your best answer was probably the comment by @P.O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I often identify the technique (with negative/hostile implications on my part) as ***name-dropping*** (when the columnist/journalist includes references to his own interactions with those people who are truly relevant to whatever is being written about, which I tend to see as "self-publicising").

But you might consider using this one from *thefreedictionary*...

> [**personalise**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Personalisation) *- to make personal, as by applying a general statement to oneself.*